# Why my JSONP Code doesn't save results into PDF file after converting from template in Google App Script

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, pdf-generation, jsonp

I'm trying to save my results into PDF file after google sheet calculation. Here's my google sheet file: [Google sheet(img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvJIr.jpg)

After someone submit my form J Column sum all answers and gets 39. Then I want to convert my template file [template(img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oF4C.jpg) to PDF, so I wrote this code:

```
function afterFormSubmit(e) {   
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    var formValues = e.namedValues;
  Logger.log(formValues);                               
        const   info = e.namedValues;
    createPDF(info);


}
                                                                                                    
function createPDF(info){                                                                                                   
                                                                                                    
const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1YPyX8gv3W-JXR0uovMdr");                                                                                                  
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1m9Xcc9hmhJjc83cSgCW26u");                                                                                                   
const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1r4m3-FtzMzlO_SmGMPuGraJhEIBsQA");                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);                                                                                                   
                                                                                                    
const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId())                                                                                                   
const body = openDoc.getBody();                                                                                                 
body.replaceText("{T}", info['Timestamp'][0]);
body.replaceText("{A2}" ,info['answer2'][0]);
body.replaceText("{A3}" ,info['answer3'][0]);   
body.replaceText("{A4}" ,info['answer4'][0]);   
body.replaceText("{A5}" ,info['answer5'][0]);       
body.replaceText("{A6}" ,info['answer6'][0]);       
body.replaceText("{A7}" ,info['answer7'][0]);               
body.replaceText("{E}", info['Email'][0]);      
body.replaceText("{R}" ,info['Results'][0]);        //Please fix it: PDF Not showing/Saving Results                                                                                             
openDoc.saveAndClose();                                                                                                 
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);                                                                                                    
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName("Quiz finish time:"+" "+ info['Timestamp'][0]);                                                                                                   
tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile); 


}
```

But when this code converts my template file to PDF he don't show/save my result {R} [PDF(img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ5OA.jpg), but all other body.replaceText(); works well. Maybe someone know how to deal with that (how to save/show Result into PDF file)?

Comment: What have you done to try to debug the problem?  Where are you losing the data?

Answer (score 0):

I get response that my google app script code is only for google form responses... So my first code didn't works to get Results... But this one is what I'm looked for:

`````
function afterFormSubmit() {
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_SHEET_ID").getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");
ss.getLastRow();
var info=ss.getRange("A"+ss.getLastRow()+":J"+ss.getLastRow()).getValues()[0];
Logger.log(info);

  createPDF(info);


}
                                                                                                    
function createPDF(info){                                                                                                   
                                                                                                
                                                                                                    
const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID");                                                                                                  
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID");                                                                                                 
const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("DOC_ID");                                                                                                 
                                                                                                    
const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);                                                                                                       
                                                                                                    
const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId())                                                                                                   
const body = openDoc.getBody();     
var dt=Utilities.formatDate(info[0],"GMT"-5.00,"MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
body.replaceText("{T}", dt);
body.replaceText("{A3}" ,info[2]);  
body.replaceText("{A4}" ,info[3]);  
body.replaceText("{A5}" ,info[4]);      
body.replaceText("{A6}" ,info[5]);      
body.replaceText("{A7}" ,info[6]);              
body.replaceText("{E}", info[7]);
body.replaceText("{A2}" ,info[8]);  
body.replaceText("{R}" ,info[9]);                                                                           
openDoc.saveAndClose();                                                                                                 
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);                                                                                                    
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName("Quiz finish time:"+" "+ dt);                                                                                                 
tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile); 


}   

````
`````